# LSTM with 2D grid timeseries input

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

So I am wondering if it is possible to have a 2D grid style input into a conventional LSTM in Keras? For example: a grid representing a room with a 1 wherever a person in standing at every time step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try ConvLSTM, which can be used to implement spatiotemporal model.